# Fancybox hide next/prev on last/first images

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2.0.4. and I would like to hide the prev button on the first image, and the next button on the last one.

I have beenc checking and I have read that a condition needs to be inserted but I don't know how to do it and where to insert it...

Could you give me a hand on this? I have tried almost every example I found in the Internet and still this is not working.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You may want to post some code to get help.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the API option `loop` (v2.x) to `false` like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    loop: false
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8VZFY/)**